# how to calculate if two vectors are 'parallel'?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know we can check if two vectors are 'orthogonal' by doing an inner product.

$a*b=0$

tells us that these two vectors are orthogonal

here comes the question:

if there a way to compute if they are 'parallel'? i.e., they are pointing at the same direction.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two vectors are parallel iff the absolute value of their dot product equals the product of their lengths.

Iff their dot product equals the product of their lengths, then they “point in the same direction”.

Comment: Hi, could you explain this further? The dot product is already a length so how can that show direction?

Comment: The dot product is not a length at all; the dot product of a vector with itself is the square of its length.

Comment: But the dot product produces a scalar. Is a scalar not a length?

Comment: Not at all.  A scalar *scales* a vector; it might be negative a s well.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you are saying. "Two vectors are parallel iff the absolute value of their dot product equals the product of their lengths." When two vectors are parallel, $cos\theta = 1$ as $\theta =0$. Going back, the definition of dot product is $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ y_1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x_2\\ \:y_2\end{pmatrix}=x_1x_2+y_{1\:}y_2$. I see it can be negative. What is a scalar then?

Comment: As I pointed out: *it is a number which scales the vector*, that is another name for a number which is multiplied by a vector.  Hence $2\cdot\vec a$ ist the vector $a$ scaled by $2$.

Comment: Ok so the dot product of two distinct vectors produces one scalar. So what vector does the scalar apply to then? Edit: Sorry I see I have forgotten the associative law

Answer (score 2):

Two parallel vectors $a$ and $b$ will have a null cross product:
$$a\times b=0\iff a\parallel b.$$

Comment: That's true only for vectors in $R^2$ and $R^3$.

Comment: See my answer concerning Gram-determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Note that two vectors $\vec v_1,\vec v_2\neq \vec 0$ are parallel $$\iff \vec v_1=k\cdot \vec v_2$$

for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$ and this condition is easy to check component by component.

For vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$ or $\mathbb{R^3}$ we could check the condition by cross product.

More in general, the matrix formed by two parallel vectors has $rank=1$.

Comment: The rank may also be zero.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I was excluding the trivial case $v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors are parallel iff their Gram-determinant, that is the area of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors, vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors are parallel iff the dimension of their span is less than $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the followings:

1) Find their slope if you have their coordinates. The slope for a vector $\vec v$ is $λ=\frac{y_v}{x_v}$. If the slope of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are equal, then they are parallel.

2) Find the if $\vec a= k\vec b$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$. If there is a value that satisfies the above equation, then they are parallel.

Comment: the first method is valid for $v\in R^2$

Comment: And it fails if one of the first coordinates is zero.  Furthermore, it suffices that the absolute values of the slopes are equal.  Second method fails if $b=0$.